# How can I reserve a block of memory from the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, hardware

I have a device that needs a block of memory that is reserved solely for it, without the OS intervening.  Is there any way to tell BIOS or the OS that a block of memory is reserved, and it must not use it?

I am using this device on an openSUSE machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you're asking for is called DMA. You need to write a driver to reserve this memory.

Yes, I realize you said you didn't want the OS to intervene, and a driver becomes part of the OS, but in absence of a driver's reservation, the kernel believes all memory belongs to it. (Unless you tell the kernel to ignore the memory block, per Aaron's answer, that is.)

[Chapter 15](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf) (PDF) of "[Linux Device Drivers, 3/e](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)" by Rubini, Corbet and Kroah-Hartmann covers DMA and related topics.

If you want an HTML version of this, I found [the second-edition version of the chapter](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html) elsewhere online. Beware that the 2nd edition is over a decade old now, having come out when kernel 2.4 was new. There's been a lot of work on the memory management subsystem of the kernel since those days, so it may not apply very well any more.

Comment: With DMA can I choose what physical addresses to use?  Will the kernel give me a contiguous block of memory?  Is it guaranteed to be always available?

Comment: Your questions are answered starting on page 442 of the PDF I pointed you to.

Answer (score 27):

If you want the OS to *totally* ignore it, you need to make a memory hole using "`memmap`." See [this reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-kernel-parameters.php). For example, if you want 512M at the 2GB barrier, you can put "`memmap=512M$2G`" on your kernel command line.

You will need to check your `dmesg` to find a contiguous hole to steal so you don't stomp on any devices; that is specific to your motherboard+cards.

This is *not* the recommended way to do things - see Warren Young's answer for how to properly do it (kernel drivers + DMA). I'm answering the exact question you asked. If you plan on making this for end users, they will *hate* you if you do this to them... trust me, that's the only reason I knew this answer.

---

Edit: If you are using grub2 w/ grubby (e.g. CentOS 7), you need to [make sure to escape the $](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=285588). There should be a single `\` before `$`. Example:

```
$ sudo -v
$ sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args=memmap='128M\\$0x57EF0000'
$ sudo grubby --info $(sudo grubby --default-kernel) | grep memmap
args="ro crashkernel=auto ... memmap=128M\$0x57EF0000"
```

Comment: Having created such a memory hole, can you then access it with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)`? If not, how? I ask here instead of posting a separate question because I assume it's a necessary part of what the OP is asking.

Comment: This is not recommended for end users.  This is for a probe I'm building for a research project for my MSc.

Comment: While your answer does answer my question directly, Warren's answer seems to be the better way to go about it. :-)

Comment: @WarrenYoung I have *no* idea what you are supposed to do with it. I would guess "`uint8_t *ptr = 0x8000000`" with my example? Or that may segfault... Huh, I really don't know. Again, I knew the answer because I was an end user of a poorly designed PCI card where I had to manually allocate a buffer below the 4G mark and then tell a driver where that space was; it may not be possible from userland.

Comment: @NathanFellman Yes and yes, I was sure to note that. ;) I even upvoted his correct answer.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: that was meant by way of explanation of why I accepted his answer even though you answered my question directly

Comment: Just for grins, I looked a little deeper into this, and it appears you need `MMAP_FIXED | MMAP_ANON`. Without a custom DMA device here to play with, I can't say if it actually does what the OP wanted, but my CentOS box happily gave me an 8 MB block at 512 MB when I said `memmap=8M$512M` in GRUB. It doesn't even require root access, as I had feared it might. But even if this does do the right thing, I still think you'll probably need a driver to handle interrupts and such.

Comment: Well, `grub` can be configured to have a password, and it doesn't need to match root's. So you used `mmap` to peek at the memory, and it didn't segfault? Cool. I guess it would have in it whatever was there from the previous reboot...

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: No, `mmap()`'d pages are zeroed before userland code gets to see them. It's done for security, so that data doesn't leak from one process to the next. Another reason to use a driver, since you might need to preserve the contents of the DMA buffer at driver load time. Oh and by the way, the arbitrarily-located `mmap()` call succeeds even without the `memmap` kernel boot option, at least as long as no one is already using memory located where you asked. The boot option doubtless increases the chances of success, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: I have written a driver to expose this memory to the user space: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12790382/143897 : explains the issue i am seeing, comments welcome ! Thanks

Comment: we have to use `numactl` to see the stolen chunks or use `dmesg  | grep -i numa`

Comment: @JayD You can do this without any coding via standard drivers like phram.

Comment: this answer is a little misleading. the `memmap` boot arg isn't really an *alternative* to writing a DMA driver. `get_free_pages` can only return a contiguous block of up to 128KB, so if your DMA driver needs a larger contiguous block, `memmap` is a completely legitimate method of achieving that. it's not a hack.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow The CMA [disagrees with you](https://lwn.net/Articles/486301/). Although that was not available when I wrote this answer nearly five years ago.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco hmm, okay. interesting. thank you for that link, it's a good read.

Answer (score 6):

To reserve a block of memory from the kernel in ARM based Linux, you can also use a `reserved-memory` node in your device tree (dts) file. In kernel documentation (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt)), there is an example:

```
memory {
    reg = <0x40000000 0x40000000>;
};

reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    ranges;

    /* global autoconfigured region for contiguous allocations */
    linux,cma {
        compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
        reusable;
        size = <0x4000000>;
        alignment = <0x2000>;
        linux,cma-default;
    };

    display_reserved: framebuffer@78000000 {
        reg = <0x78000000 0x800000>;
    };

    multimedia_reserved: multimedia@77000000 {
        compatible = "acme,multimedia-memory";
        reg = <0x77000000 0x4000000>;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First enter this command, to check your current setting:

```
sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes
```

To change the set value, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Look for the line:

```
vm.min_free_kbytes=12888
```

If it doesn't exist, create it (along with your desired value). The following values are acceptable:

```
8192
12288
16384
20480
```

8M is extremely conservative; it can sit at 16M comfortably. Once you change the value, run this and no reboot is needed:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Please don't blank your posts; either delete it or flag it for a moderator to remove for you.