# How do I reserve a range of page frames just for my kernel driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, kernel-modules, boot-loader

I have a specific set of page frame numbers (PFNs, memory) that I want to 
reserve for my kernel driver. How do I do that? Can I do it at boot 
time?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Try reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel) ... in arm linux, do it via the _device tree_