# How to read/write system RAM via physical address

Tags: linux, memory

My system is based on x86(64-bit) and it has 8GB RAM.
I have set reserve 100MB of 8GB using memmap=100M@0x40000000.

For this way does it guarantee to reserve the 100M of RAM? Can I access the 100MB of RAM using address 0x40000000 in both user and kernel space? Of course I understand to need translate the physical to virtual address.

Comment: In particular, the [second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37735/28235) that explains why `memmap` isn't usually a good idea anyway. ;)