# Allow partial memory mapping of /dev/mem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fpga, memory-mapped-file

I have a SoC-FPGA(DE0-nano-soc) which contains an ARM-Cortex-A9 cpu with a Cyclone V FPGA on a single chip. the CPU has access to 1gb of DDR3 memory but the FPGA can also access this memory so they can share data.

Now I have configured linux to only see 900M of the total RAM using the boot parameter `mem=900M`. This way I have some RAM left linux doesn't touch that I can use to communicate with the FPGA. I want to write to that part of the RAM using `/dev/mem`. I get a permission denied error when I memory map the appropriate address, I am guessing this is because my kernel has `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` set.

Now I don't really want to unset this since I really only need to write to adresses which linux doesn't use. Is there a way to tell the linux kernel that it is fine to write to that specific part but the normal memory is still of limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this: https://docs.pmem.io/getting-started-guide/creating-development-environments/linux-environments/linux-memmap

Assuming you have a new enough kernel, adding `memmap=124!900` should make the desired memory accessible as `/dev/pmem0` .

It advises to also add `nokaslr`, otherwise you may get random system errors.  KASLR is a security feature which makes it harder to exploit the kernel.

Although this has been used for [fascinating hacks](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20190420153148.21548-1-pasha.tatashin@soleen.com/), I am not able to recommend it for your case.  I do not know how to manage the CPU caches v.s. updates from the FPGA (aka DMA).  And our advice on [other questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel) is not to do this :-).

---

There's also another option, though it doesn't answer the question as written.  I think you can boot with `iomem=relaxed`, if you wanted to temporarily disable STRICT_DEVMEM without compiling a whole new kernel.

Comment: In the end I will write a device driver to handle the access part. Reads/writes from FPGA to the RAM are non coherent so using the /dev/mem interface would have introduced issues anyway. But for now I just want to test the interface from both linux and from the FPGA so I know this is all wired up correctly. Then I will make a nice device driver :). Thank you for answering my question and pointing to relevant materials!

Comment: Just as a quick comment `memmap=900!124` would reserve 900 at offset 124. I want to reserve 124 at offset 900 so the correct option would be  `memmap=124!900`.