# How do I reserve a large block of memory from the Linux kernel for device/DMA use?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, memory

I want to reserve a large amount (~1 gigabyte) of contiguous memory for DMA from a device. The entire purpose of this particular Linux box is to run a single application which uses the device. The device does large transfers of ~10-200MB per operation.

To be clear, put up this question for the next guy. Expect to have an answer somewhat shortly.

Comment: To be clear, the Linux kernel has well-described support for allocating DMA buffers. The problem is with large buffers. This seems to be a continuing topic.
https://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/#Memory_management-Large_allocations

There are distinct large-allocations use cases. General purpose use is hard and (so far) unsolved. Specialized cases are more solvable. 

This question and answers are good, but fail to distinguish use-cases.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel

Comment: Also check https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages

Comment: In my case, I want to have four 256MB blocks for DMA from the device. The device is an FPGA with streams from four sources at ~4GB/s each. No need for any sort of general purpose pool (how I read CMA) - in fact reason not. Pattern of allocation is fixed.

Comment: For completeness, will note I used ``memmap=4G!4G`` successfully for a time. Most of the development team is in fact still using this version. Then the FPGA design entirely changed, so I am now using the Xilinx XDMA driver for transfers to and from FPGA attached DDR4. The upside is no kernel parameters needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to. Instead, you'll have to "fake it" as [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37735/8965).

The last time I checked (it's been a while), the [CMA](https://lwn.net/Articles/486301/) hadn't been ported to x86 from ARM yet. Even then, that big a buffer is unlikely to work out for you.

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is in the direction of adding "memmap=1G$4G" as a kernel boot parameter. Still walking through how to use that reserved 1GB of memory.

Comment: Yes, that horrible answer was also to get large FPGA DMA pools.